# how to use login_url in telegram bot with php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

hi guy does anyone knows about using inline keyboard in telegram bot for login_url ?

i just write this code for inlinekeyboard to take users to my website and login with telegram but it doesnt work
my code:

$replyuser=array(
inline_keyboard=>array(
array(array('text'=>urlencode("login \xE2\xAD\x90"),'callback_data'=>'log'.$chatid,array('login_url'=>array(array('url'=>'https://mywebsite.com/login.php','request_write_access'=>TRUE)))))
),
);

i dont know how to use login-url object in telegram with this format

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest using `[]` instead of `array()`
2. Beautify your code, and format it to be clear

```php
$replyuser = [
    'inline_keyboard' => [[
        [
            'text' => urlencode("login \xE2\xAD\x90"),
            'callback_data' => 'log'.$chatid
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'Login to the website'
            'login_url' => [
                'url' => 'https://mywebsite.com/login.php',
                'request_write_access' => true
            ]
       ]
    ]]
];
```